# Edge browser remembers last PDF view settings

Tags: angular, iframe, microsoft-edge, pdf-viewer

I have an angular app where we show a PDF report (downloaded via an API) in an iFrame.

.TS code:

```
this.subscription = this.reportservice.execute().subscribe((response: Blob) => {
      let file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(fileURL);
    }, (error) => {
    });
```

.html code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="900px" frameBorder="0" [src]="url"></iframe>
```

Somehow Edge browser remembers zoom/page number settings when it was last viewed and loads the next report using the last viewed settings. Edge browser has a setting to disable this. However, this needs to be done for all users. Is there anyway programmatically force it to forget last viewed settings? Unfortunately it remembers the settings even for different report

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comments. I tried adding unique query string but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the query strings, mentioned by **K J**, are not respected within an iframe. Pulling the PDF outside the iframe should make the query strings work (if you can).

Anyway, **Open PDFs to last viewed location when you reopen files** is turned on by default, partly because this feature was requested by a large number of users before.